# Exportar módulos no angular 8

Tags: angular

Estou tentando exportar um módulo com seus components para usar no app-module, porém estou tendo o seguinte erro ao abrir:

```
'app-AmbevComponent' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-AmbevComponent' is an Angular component, then verify that it is         part of this module.
2. If 'app-AmbevComponent' is a Web Component then add     'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress     this message. ("
</div>
```

Criei um módulo e dentro deste módulo criei um component, coloquei este mesmo component para ser exportado e importei o módulo no app-module.

No module exportei o component:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AmbevModuleComponent } from './AmbevModule.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [AmbevModuleComponent],
  exports: [AmbevModuleComponent] <- exportei aqui
})
export class AmbevModuleModule { }
```

Meu compoment:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-AmbevComponent',
  templateUrl: './AmbevComponent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./AmbevComponent.component.css']
})
export class AmbevComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

e o app.module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { TooltipModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tooltip';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';
import { AmbevModuleModule } from './AmbevModule/AmbevModule.module';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      NavComponent
   ],
       imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      BrowserAnimationsModule,
      BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
      TooltipModule.forRoot(),
      ModalModule.forRoot(),
      AppRoutingModule,
      HttpClientModule,
      FormsModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule,
      AmbevModuleModule <- importei aqui
   ],
   providers: [],
   bootstrap: [
      AppComponent
   ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Coloquei no app.component.html a seguinte tag

```
<app-AmbevComponent></app-AmbevComponent>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você declarou e exportou o próprio módulo `AmbevModuleModule`. Basta ajustar o `declarations` e o `exports` para o componente `AmbevComponentComponent`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AmbevModuleComponent } from './AmbevModule.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [AmbevComponentComponent ], // <- Correção
  exports: [AmbevComponentComponent ] // <- Correção
})
export class AmbevModuleModule { }
```

Comment: Marcelo, obrigado pela resposta, no caso eu declarei o component dentro do module e exportei o mesmo component, não está certo? Declarei o component e exportei ele dentro do module. No caso, o nome está como AmbevModuleComponent pois foi criado dentro de um diretório chamado AmbevModule.

Comment: @RonaldoAlves segundo seu post dentro do `AmbevModuleModule` foi declarado e exportado o próprio módulo `AmbevModuleComponent`. Por esta razão seu componente não foi exportado. Basta alterar onde deixei indicado para que seu componente, `AmbevComponentComponent`, seja declarado dentro do módulo e exportado.

Comment: Resolvido, valeu.